# Azure search filter Edm.DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I have an azure search index for a table with a field with datatype Edm.DateTimeOffset. And the following filter:
$filter=MyDateTimeOffset ge '4/14/2017 6:35:05 AM +00:00' and MyDateTimeOffset le '4/14/2017 7:45:01 AM +00:00'

Invalid expression: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'LessThanOrEqual'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"

EDIT:

Problem solved, I changed my datetime format to: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ and removed the quotes

Example: $filter=Timestamp ge 2017-04-14T06:35:05Z

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please copy your solution into an answer so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem solved, I changed my datetime format to: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ and removed the quotes

Example: $filter=Timestamp ge 2017-04-14T06:35:05Z

Comment: For c#, you'd use `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")` to get the correct format.

Comment: This works with GET Verb but with POST, I am using filter like : `{"filter":"Date ge 2017-04-14T06:35:05Z","top":100,"skip":0,"orderby":"code asc","count":true,"search":"*"}` and it give 400 with below response `{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. Unexpected end of input was found in JSON content. Not all object and array scopes were closed.\r\n"
    }
}`